# Multiply numbers with using Recursive function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

For the tables below, I need to write a query that will generate the desired output. How can i solve this question using with recursive function.

Note: I solved with EXP(SUM(LOG(Value))) AS ValueMultiplication but i need to solve with recursive.

Logic :

30.0 x 3.0 x 0.5 -> 45

5.0 x 7.0 ->35

1.0 x 2.0 x 3.0 x 5.0 ->30

2.0 x 0.1 x 3.0 ->0.6

0.1 ->0.1

[image]

Table Values :

```
WITH
EXPERIMENT(ExperimentId,Code) AS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM(VALUES(1,'A10'),
               (2,'A20'),
               (3,'C40'),
               (4,'B00'),
               (5,'B99')
    )EXPERIMENT (ExperimentId,Code)),

MEASUREMENT(ExperimentId,Value) AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM(VALUES(1,30.0),
               (1,3.0),
               (1,0.5),
               (2,5.0),
               (2,7.0),
               (3,0.1),
               (4,1.0),
               (4,2.0),
               (4,3.0),
               (4,5.0),
               (5,2.0),
               (5,0.1),
               (5,3.0)
        )MEASUREMENT(ExperimentId,Value)),
```

Comment: Mr. Linoff sir please help me  (i'm sure you will look this post :D)

Comment: 30 x 3 x 0.5 = 45

Comment: oh yes i edited it

Comment: In case anyone needs it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec1bed5/5

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, using your table value constructors for the source data (omitted for clarity from the query). It first computes row numbers, ordering by `Value` ascending and descending, and then uses the ascending row numbers to order the input values to recursively multiply them (and count the number of them) and the descending row number to select the final product from that CTE:

```sql
ROWS AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExperimentID ORDER BY Value) AS rn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExperimentID ORDER BY Value DESC) AS rnd
    FROM MEASUREMENT
),
MULTIPLES AS (
    SELECT ExperimentId, CAST(Value AS FLOAT) AS Value, rn, rnd
    FROM ROWS
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ExperimentId, r.Value * m.Value, r.rn, r.rnd
    FROM ROWS r
    JOIN MULTIPLES m ON r.ExperimentId = m.ExperimentId AND r.rn = m.rn + 1
)
SELECT e.Code AS ExperimentCode,
       m.rn AS ValueCount,
       m.Value AS ValueMultiplication
FROM EXPERIMENT e
JOIN MULTIPLES m ON m.ExperimentID = e.ExperimentID
WHERE m.rnd = 1
ORDER BY m.Value DESC
```

Output:

```
ExperimentCode  ValueCount  ValueMultiplication
A10             3           45
A20             2           35
B00             4           30
B99             3           0.6
C40             1           0.1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=023168dfbf6d3f3761a884891cb8cff4)

Comment: i liked your `r.rn = m.rn + 1` trick. i was struggling without it. thanks for teaching this.

Comment: @brunoff no worries - I'm glad you found this useful.